# Configuration Manager

Tags: c++, c++17

The idea here is to implement a configuration system using INI files for a pathfinding library nammed [Kraken](https://github.com/PFGimenez/The-Kraken-Pathfinding). This library is in java and I am helping implementing it in C++. The goal is to make it cross platform and to specificaly aim embedded systems. For now the INI parser uses [inih](http://code.google.com/p/inih/) for simplicity, but should be able to run without file system in the end (with an INI parser that can parse an INI formated string without loading it from a file). We also want to avoid using streams in the release build.

The parameters are stored in modules. Each module can have its parameters changed at runtime to adapt the pathfinding to the situation. This is done by changing the INI section for the desired module. For each module, the user can register function pointers that are called when its section changes.

The parameters have hard coded default values and the INI file should have a defaut section containing all parameter values. The code should follow [ROS style guidelines](http://wiki.ros.org/CppStyleGuide).

A few inelegant things bother me:

- The enum to string conversion
- Finding the module related with a specific ConfigKey
- The use of the ConfigurationParameter struct and the hardcoded default values (a lot of code is here only for this part to work)

Thank you for your time and your advices on this, I really appreciate it.

ConfigurationHandler.h

```
#ifndef CONFIGURATION_HANDLER_H
#define CONFIGURATION_HANDLER_H

#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <optional>

#include "configuration_module.h"
#include "iniReader/INIReader.h"

/*
 * The order of this enum is important as it gives an easy way
 * to get the relation between a parameter and its module using
 * the first key of each group.
 * If you have to modify this enum, keep the groups in the same
 * order and let the first key of each group at the first place.
 */
namespace ConfigKeys
{
    enum class ConfigKeys
    {
        //Navmesh parameters
        NavmeshObstaclesDilatation = 0,
        LargestTriangleAreaInNavmesh,
        LongestEdgeInNavmesh,
        NavmeshFilename,

        //Auto replanning
        NecessaryMargin,
        PreferedMargin,
        MarginBeforeCollision,
        InitialMargin,

        //Research and mechanical parameters
        MaxCurvatureDerivative,
        MaxLateralAcceleration,
        MaxLinearAcceleration,
        DefaultMaxSpeed,
        MinimalSpeed,
        MaxCurvature,
        StopDuration,
        SearchTimeout,
        ThreadNumber,
        EnableDebug,
        FastAndDirty,
        CheckNewObstacles,
        AllowBackwardMotion,

        //Memory management parameters
        NodeMemoryPoolSize,
        ObstaclesMemoryPoolSize,

        //Tentacle parameters
        PrecisionTrace,
        NbPoints
    };
}
using ConfigKey = ConfigKeys::ConfigKeys ;

namespace ConfigModules
{
    enum class ConfigModules
    {
        Navmesh = 0,        //Require to regenerate the navmesh
        Autoreplanning,     //Can be modified on-the-fly
        ResearchMechanical, //Can be modified on-the-fly
        Memory,             //Require to recreate the pools
        Tentacle,
        Unknown
    };
}
using ConfigModule = ConfigModules::ConfigModules ;

class ConfigurationHandler
{
private:
    //Structure holding all possible types of parameter value.
    //It should be an union, but it will require a bit more work because of the std::string
    struct ConfigurationParameter
    {
        double numeric_value;
        bool boolean_value;
        std::string string_value;

        ConfigurationParameter() = default;
        ConfigurationParameter(double value) { numeric_value = value; }
        ConfigurationParameter(int value) { numeric_value = value; }
        ConfigurationParameter(bool value) { boolean_value = value; }
        ConfigurationParameter(std::string value) { string_value = value; }
    };

public:
    ConfigurationHandler(const std::string& filename);

    void registerCallback(ConfigModule module_enum, ConfigurationCallback callback);
    void changeModuleSection(ConfigModule module_enum, std::string new_section);
    void changeModuleSection(std::vector<ConfigModule>&& modules, std::string new_section);

    long getInt(ConfigKey key, ConfigModule module = ConfigModule::Unknown);
    double getDouble(ConfigKey key, ConfigModule module = ConfigModule::Unknown);
    bool getBool(ConfigKey key, ConfigModule module = ConfigModule::Unknown);
    std::string getString(ConfigKey key, ConfigModule module = ConfigModule::Unknown);

private:
    ConfigModule getModuleEnumFromKeyEnum(ConfigKey key) const noexcept;
    std::string findSectionName(ConfigKey key, ConfigModule module_key);
    void setDefaultValues();
    inline std::string getKeyName(ConfigKey key);
    std::optional<ConfigurationModule> getModule(ConfigModule module);

    //Helper function for default values initialization
    template<typename T>
    void doAddDefaultValue(ConfigKey key, T value)
    {
        default_values_[(int)key] = ConfigurationParameter{value};
    }

    INIReader ini_reader_;
    std::vector<ConfigurationModule> modules_;
    std::vector<ConfigurationParameter> default_values_;
    static constexpr int configuration_key_count = (int)ConfigKey::NbPoints + 1;
    static constexpr int module_count = (int)ConfigModule::Tentacle + 1;

    //The array that keeps the string values of the ConfigKeys
    const std::string configuration_key_string_values[configuration_key_count] = {
            "NavmeshObstaclesDilatation", "LargestTriangleAreaInNavmesh", "LongestEdgeInNavmesh", "NavmeshFilename",
            "NecessaryMargin", "PreferedMargin", "MarginBeforeCollision", "InitialMargin", "MaxCurvatureDerivative",
            "MaxLateralAcceleration", "MaxLinearAcceleration", "DefaultMaxSpeed", "MinimalSpeed", "MaxCurvature",
            "StopDuration", "SearchTimeout", "ThreadNumber", "EnableDebug", "FastAndDirty", "CheckNewObstacles",
            "AllowBackwardMotion", "NodeMemoryPoolSize", "ObstaclesMemoryPoolSize", "PrecisionTrace", "NbPoints"
    };
};

#endif //CONFIGURATION_HANDLER_H
```

ConfigurationHandler.cpp

```
#include "configuration_handler.h"

ConfigurationHandler::ConfigurationHandler(const std::string& filename) :
    ini_reader_{filename},
    modules_(module_count),
    default_values_(configuration_key_count)
{
    setDefaultValues();
}

long ConfigurationHandler::getInt(ConfigKey key, ConfigModule module)
{
    auto defaultValue = static_cast<int>(default_values_[static_cast<int>(key)].numeric_value);
    auto sectionName = findSectionName(key, module);
    return ini_reader_.GetInteger(sectionName, getKeyName(key), defaultValue);
}

double ConfigurationHandler::getDouble(ConfigKey key, ConfigModule module)
{
    auto defaultValue = default_values_[static_cast<int>(key)].numeric_value;
    auto sectionName = findSectionName(key, module);
    return ini_reader_.GetReal(sectionName, getKeyName(key), defaultValue);
}

bool ConfigurationHandler::getBool(ConfigKey key, ConfigModule module)
{
    auto defaultValue = default_values_[static_cast<int>(key)].boolean_value;
    auto sectionName = findSectionName(key, module);
    return ini_reader_.GetBoolean(sectionName, getKeyName(key), defaultValue);
}

std::string ConfigurationHandler::getString(ConfigKey key, ConfigModule module)
{
    auto defaultValue = default_values_[static_cast<int>(key)].string_value;
    auto sectionName = findSectionName(key, module);
    return ini_reader_.Get(sectionName, getKeyName(key), defaultValue);
}

void ConfigurationHandler::registerCallback(ConfigModule module_enum, ConfigurationCallback callback)
{
    auto module = getModule(module_enum);
    if(module)
    {
        module->registerCallback(callback);
    }
}

void ConfigurationHandler::changeModuleSection(ConfigModule module_enum, std::string new_section)
{
    auto module = getModule(module_enum);
    if(module)
    {
        module->changeSection(*this, new_section);
    }
}

void ConfigurationHandler::changeModuleSection(std::vector<ConfigModule>&& modules, std::string new_section)
{
    for(auto module : modules)
    {
        changeModuleSection(module, new_section);
    }
}

std::string ConfigurationHandler::findSectionName(ConfigKey key, ConfigModule module_key)
{
    if(module_key == ConfigModule::Unknown)
    {
        module_key = getModuleEnumFromKeyEnum(key);
    }

    return modules_[static_cast<int>(module_key)].getCurrentSection();
}

std::string ConfigurationHandler::getKeyName(ConfigKey key)
{
    return configuration_key_string_values[static_cast<int>(key)];
}

ConfigModule ConfigurationHandler::getModuleEnumFromKeyEnum(ConfigKey key) const noexcept
{
    //I'm not proud of this function, but I could'nt find a better solution yet.
    if(key < ConfigKey::NecessaryMargin)
    {
        return ConfigModule::Navmesh;
    }
    else if(key < ConfigKey::MaxCurvatureDerivative)
    {
        return ConfigModule::Autoreplanning;
    }
    else if(key < ConfigKey::NodeMemoryPoolSize)
    {
        return ConfigModule::ResearchMechanical;
    }
    else if(key < ConfigKey::PrecisionTrace)
    {
        return ConfigModule::Memory;
    }
    else
    {
        return ConfigModule::Tentacle;
    }
}

std::optional<ConfigurationModule> ConfigurationHandler::getModule(ConfigModule module)
{
    auto moduleId = static_cast<int>(module);
    if(moduleId < module_count)
    {
        return modules_[moduleId];
    }
    else
    {
        return std::nullopt;
    }
}

void ConfigurationHandler::setDefaultValues()
{
    doAddDefaultValue<int>(ConfigKey::NavmeshObstaclesDilatation, 100);
    doAddDefaultValue<int>(ConfigKey::LargestTriangleAreaInNavmesh, 20000);
    doAddDefaultValue<int>(ConfigKey::LongestEdgeInNavmesh, 200);
    doAddDefaultValue<std::string>(ConfigKey::NavmeshFilename, "navmesh.krk");
    doAddDefaultValue<int>(ConfigKey::NecessaryMargin, 40);
    doAddDefaultValue<int>(ConfigKey::PreferedMargin, 60);
    doAddDefaultValue<int>(ConfigKey::MarginBeforeCollision, 100);
    doAddDefaultValue<int>(ConfigKey::InitialMargin, 100);
    doAddDefaultValue<int>(ConfigKey::MaxCurvatureDerivative, 5);
    doAddDefaultValue<int>(ConfigKey::MaxLateralAcceleration, 3);
    doAddDefaultValue<int>(ConfigKey::MaxLinearAcceleration, 2);
    doAddDefaultValue<int>(ConfigKey::DefaultMaxSpeed, 1);
    doAddDefaultValue<int>(ConfigKey::MinimalSpeed, 0);
    doAddDefaultValue<int>(ConfigKey::MaxCurvature, 5);
    doAddDefaultValue<int>(ConfigKey::StopDuration, 800);
    doAddDefaultValue<int>(ConfigKey::SearchTimeout, 10000);
    doAddDefaultValue<int>(ConfigKey::ThreadNumber, 1);
    doAddDefaultValue<bool>(ConfigKey::EnableDebug, true);
    doAddDefaultValue<bool>(ConfigKey::FastAndDirty, false);
    doAddDefaultValue<bool>(ConfigKey::CheckNewObstacles, false);
    doAddDefaultValue<int>(ConfigKey::NodeMemoryPoolSize, 20000);
    doAddDefaultValue<int>(ConfigKey::ObstaclesMemoryPoolSize, 50000);
    doAddDefaultValue<bool>(ConfigKey::AllowBackwardMotion, true);
    doAddDefaultValue<int>(ConfigKey::NbPoints, 5);
    doAddDefaultValue<float>(ConfigKey::PrecisionTrace, 0.02f);
}
```

ConfigurationModule.h

```
#ifndef CONFIGURATION_MODULE_H
#define CONFIGURATION_MODULE_H

#include <string>

#include "configuration_callback_holder.h"

class ConfigurationHandler;

class ConfigurationModule
{
public:
    void registerCallback(ConfigurationCallback callback);
    void changeSection(ConfigurationHandler& configuration_handler, std::string new_section);
    std::string getCurrentSection();
private:
    ConfigurationCallbackHolder callbacks_holder_;
    std::string current_section_ = {"default"};
};


#endif //CONFIGURATION_MODULE_H
```

ConfigurationModule.cpp

```
#include "configuration_module.h"

void ConfigurationModule::registerCallback(ConfigurationCallback callback)
{
    callbacks_holder_ += callback;
}

void ConfigurationModule::changeSection(ConfigurationHandler& configuration_handler, std::string new_section)
{
    if(new_section != current_section_)
    {
        current_section_ = new_section;
        callbacks_holder_(configuration_handler);
    }
}

std::string ConfigurationModule::getCurrentSection()
{
    return current_section_;
}
```

ConfigurationCallbackHolder.h

```
#ifndef CONFIGURATION_CALLBACK_HOLDER_H
#define CONFIGURATION_CALLBACK_HOLDER_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

class ConfigurationHandler;
using ConfigurationCallback = std::function<void(ConfigurationHandler&)>;

class ConfigurationCallbackHolder
{
public:
    void operator+=(const ConfigurationCallback callback);
    void operator()(ConfigurationHandler& configuration_handler) const;
private:
    std::vector<ConfigurationCallback> callbacks_;
};


#endif //CONFIGURATION_CALLBACK_HOLDER_H
```

ConfigurationCallbackHolder.cpp

```
#include "configuration_callback_holder.h"

void ConfigurationCallbackHolder::operator+=(const ConfigurationCallback callback)
{
    callbacks_.push_back(callback);
}

void ConfigurationCallbackHolder::operator()(ConfigurationHandler& configuration_handler) const
{
    auto iterator = callbacks_.cbegin();
    for(; iterator != callbacks_.cend(); ++iterator)
    {
        (*iterator)(configuration_handler);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//The array that keeps the string values of the ConfigKeys
const std::string configuration_key_string_values[configuration_key_count] = {
        "NavmeshObstaclesDilatation", "LargestTriangleAreaInNavmesh", "LongestEdgeInNavmesh", "NavmeshFilename", ⋯
```

When I have an array like this for names or other purpose, where the actual enumeration values are significant, I will use at least an explicit initializer on the first one (as did you) but also comments *there* explaining that.  Furthermore, all places that must be updated as well when you change the enumeration will be marked with some unique word that can be grepped for (and that is part of the commentary).

You might be interested in the short video “Enums 4 Ways” at CppCon (née BoostCon) 2018, posted to YouTube last week.

Do the enumeration values need to be a contiguous range of small integers (e.g. used in `switch` statements, stored in small words) or just serve as compile-time unique values?

Because another thing you can do is define named constants rather than enumerators.  If the C++ symbol is itself a lex string, you automatically have the correspondence at least in one direction!

```
 struct my_enum_thing {
     static const char* const NavmeshObstaclesDilatation = "NavmeshObstaclesDilatation";
     // etc.
```

The actual value of the symbol is a pointer, and unique.  But, they are the full word size, and not consecutive numbers.

You might use an “X Macro” approach to define everything from one supplied list of names.

---

```
const std::string configuration_key_string_values[configuration_key_count] =
```

You don’t need to give the array size (and have those previous lines to figure it out), as it will simply match the initializer count.

You are creating all the string objects at run-time, which will duplicate the bytes of the string.  So you will have the original lex strings still in your read-only data, and the std::strings with pointers to heap memory containing the same contents.  And all that copying has to happen at program-start.

Make the array a `constexpr` itself, and use `std::string_view` values.  You can construct the string view wrapper at compile time, and it points back to the lex string, without duplication.

```
using namespace std::literals::string_view_literals;

constexpr std::string_view config_values[]= {
    "NavmeshObstaclesDilatation"sv, "LargestTriangleAreaInNavmesh"sv, ⋯
```

**Note the `sv` on following the closing quote.**

The advantage of making the array of string view, rather than plain lex strings, is that code does not have to call `strlen` when using them.

---

```
long ConfigurationHandler::getInt(ConfigKey key, ConfigModule module)
{
    auto defaultValue = static_cast<int>(default_values_[static_cast<int>(key)].numeric_value);
    auto sectionName = findSectionName(key, module);
    return ini_reader_.GetInteger(sectionName, getKeyName(key), defaultValue);
}

double ConfigurationHandler::getDouble(ConfigKey key, ConfigModule module)
{
    auto defaultValue = default_values_[static_cast<int>(key)].numeric_value;
    auto sectionName = findSectionName(key, module);
    return ini_reader_.GetReal(sectionName, getKeyName(key), defaultValue);
}

bool ConfigurationHandler::getBool(ConfigKey key, ConfigModule module)
{
    auto defaultValue = default_values_[static_cast<int>(key)].boolean_value;
    auto sectionName = findSectionName(key, module);
    return ini_reader_.GetBoolean(sectionName, getKeyName(key), defaultValue);

⋯ etc. ⋯
```

I’m seeing a lot of repetition here, as well as conceptually a single operation that should be parameterized on type.  You should make it a template, so most of the code is naturally shared.  If `ini_reader` is a 3rd party library and not template friendly in this same way, you just have to supply one-line wrappers, not duplicate the whole body.

```
x = config.get<long>(key, module);
y = config.get<double> (key2, module);
z - config.get<bool> (key3, module);
```

Oh, and my syntax highlighting is reminding me that `module` is reserved as a new reserved word.  So don’t use it as a variable name!

---

```
auto module = getModule(module_enum);
if(module)
{
    module->registerCallback(callback);
}
```

The idiom is to initialize *and test* at the same time.  The advantage is that the variable is only in scope if it is correct to use!

```
if (auto module = getModule(module_enum))
{
    module->registerCallback(callback);
}
```

---

```
ConfigModule ConfigurationHandler::getModuleEnumFromKeyEnum(ConfigKey key) const noexcept
{
    //I'm not proud of this function, but I could'nt find a better solution yet.
    if(key < ConfigKey::NecessaryMargin)
    {
        return ConfigModule::Navmesh;
    }
    else if(key < ConfigKey::MaxCurvatureDerivative)
    {
        return ConfigModule::Autoreplanning;
    }
    else if(key < ConfigKey::NodeMemoryPoolSize)
    {
        return ConfigModule::ResearchMechanical;
    }
    else if(key < ConfigKey::PrecisionTrace)
    {
        return ConfigModule::Memory;
    }
    else
    {
        return ConfigModule::Tentacle;
    }
}
```

Put the pairs of values in an array.  So

```
{ ConfigKey::NecessaryMargin, ConfigModule::Navmesh },
{ ConfigKey::MaxCurvatureDerivative, ConfigModule::Autoreplanning },
    ⋮
```

Then you can write the logic *once*, iterating over the tuples of parameters.

```
for (auto [ck, cm] : the_list) {
    if (key < ck)  return cm;
}
// none of the above
return ConfigModule::Temtacle;
```

This is a general concept and working through it here will probably help you in more places.

Another idea, if you can be flexible about the assignment of code numbers, is to code the bunch in the high-order bits.  So something like

```
enum ⋯ { NecessaryMargin= 0, ⋯
         MaxCurvatureDerivative = 0x1'0000,
         MaxLateralAcceleration, // continue auto-numbering
```

Now you can examine the high bits of the enumeration’s value to recover the module that goes with it.

---

```
    if(moduleId < module_count)
    {
        return modules_[moduleId];
    }
    else
    {
        return std::nullopt;
    }
```

Look at the code generated when you call this!

Writing it to allow NVRO is much cleaner.

```
std::optional<ConfigurationModule> retval;
if (moduleId < module_count)
    retval.emplace(modules_[moduleId]);
return retval;
```

---

The default values could be built at compile time, not copied into a vector at run time.  Try setting them up in sorted order in an array, and then find it using `std::lower_bound` etc.  BTW, `std::map` uses a lot of (dynamic) memory and is slow; a sorted vector is faster for lookups!

---

Good luck with that project — it looks interesting!

Comment: Thanks a lot for these informations. I find a lot of interesting things in your answer!

Comment: I am amazed by the amount of things I learned from one single answer. Thank you for taking the time to share your knowledge here.